# CSS aligning sprite in List element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-sprites

I have this list menu and I want to display arrows for each of the items so when you hover over the item the arrow changes the color. So far my problem seems to be aligning this arrow vertically centered compared to the text. As you can see from the screenshot it is slightly off. Ignore the missing space between the arrow and the hyperlink.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xbse/

[image: Screenshot]

HTML,

```
<li ><a class="clear-block" href="http://wordpress.local/archives/category/announcements" title="View all posts filed under Announcements">
 <span class="tt">Announcements <strong>(1)</strong></span>
 <span class="c1"></span>
</a></li>
<li ><a class="clear-block" href="http://wordpress.local/archives/category/c-sharp" title="View all posts filed under C#">
 <span class="tt">C# <strong>(1)</strong></span>
 <span class="c1"></span>
</a></li>
<li  class="extends"><a class="clear-block" href="http://wordpress.local/archives/category/c-plus-plus" title="View all posts filed under C++">
 <span class="tt">C++ <strong>(1)</strong></span>
 <span class="c1"></span>
</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li ><a class="clear-block" href="http://wordpress.local/archives/category/c-plus-plus/multiplexing-io" title="View all posts filed under Multiplexing I/O">
 <span class="tt">Multiplexing I/O <strong>(1)</strong></span>
 <span class="c1"></span>
</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

CSS,

```
.block ul.menu, .block ul.menu ul, .block ul.menu li, .block .box, .block .box .entry{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  line-height: normal;
}

.block ul.menu li, .block ul.box .entry{
  border-bottom:1px dotted #aaa;
  border-top:1px dotted #fff;
}

/* no border on 1st list item */
.block ul.menu li.first,
.block ul.menu li:first-child,
.block ul.box .entry.first,
.block ul.box .entry:first-child{border-top:0 !important;}

.block ul.menu li.last,
.block ul.menu li:last-child,
.block ul.box .entry.last,
.block ul.box .entry:last-child{border-bottom:0 !important;}

.block ul.menu li .expand{display: none;}

.block ul.menu li, .block ul.box .entry {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.block ul.menu li a {
  background:transparent url(../images/icons_old.png) no-repeat 4px -816px;
}

/* titles */
.block ul.menu .tt {
  display:block;
}

.block ul.menu a:hover .tt{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

/* content - primary */
.block ul.menu .c1{
  display:block;
  line-height: 150%;
  color:#333;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/* information block (left side) */
.block ul.menu .base {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: can you please post your "icons_old.png" or a working jsFiddle file

Comment: Sorry. Its here -> http://imgur.com/UHZe3.
Il try and get a working Fiddle going.

Comment: Ive uploaded the code to fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/7xbse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of having a sprite image which did not take into account the height of the menu rows. So the arrow was unaligned. The trick was to fix the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a giant CSS sprite, why not just save each image individually and take advantage of the fact that `background-position: 0 50%` will vertically-center your image?